# Heroku Deployment MEVN Stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I've deployed my MEVN stack app to Heroku and can access it from my development machine. I can add and delete items on the mlab mongodb I have setup.  If I try to access from my phone or another machine the website works but I can't see the data.  I have searched and can't find anything related to this.  I am afraid it is obvious but I don't see it. Below is the website link.

https://dry-earth-62210.herokuapp.com/#/users

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/api', //base URL goes here
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As baseUrl, use 'https://dry-earth-62210.herokuapp.com/api' instead of 'http://localhost:8080/api'. You are good to go.

Right now you are trying to invoke local server from Heroku app and your local server is not available to the Heroku app.

Your API request code should be,

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://dry-earth-62210.herokuapp.com/api', //base URL goes here
});
```

Also, make sure, your CORS is enabled for all sites or well configured. Otherwise, there might be some Cross-Origin Error issue.

Comment: Thanks, I think that got it, my local instance is calling the heroku API but now I can't get heroku to take the changes.

Comment: Glad to help you. Will you then, please, make the answer accepted by clicking the check mark?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your API call - if you look at the request URL, it's pinging `localhost:8080`. You'll need to change this from the hardcoded `localhost:8080` value to dynamically get the server's address. (This is probably where you're doing `app.listen`).

Feel free to post your main `index.js` file and I can take a closer look :)

[image: Network request]

Comment: Thanks, I found it in the http.js, I looked everywhere else and couldn't find it.  What would be the correct way to declare it?

Comment: Ah, perfect - that's the correct line you need to change :)

Comment: Is your API also hosted at this same Heroku link?

Comment: Yes, I was a little unsure about how that fit together.

Comment: Hmm...you shouldn't have to make an API call if what you're calling is in the same app. You should be able to export the functions which would've been called by the API request and just call them directly.
Do you have a GitHub link with the code?

Comment: [Github Repo](https://github.com/Rsteen76/greentree). I am trying to learn the MEVN stack and there are a lot of ways to set things up.  I am open to the idea that this might not be the cleanest.  I was just trying to use an API backend.

Comment: In that case, Sham's suggestion should work ^.^
Just keep in mind that if you try to re-deploy somewhere else and end up with a different URL, you'll have to change that again